# Custom color palettes not visible to other layers?

Tags: qgis, style, color

Full-disclosure: fairly new to QGIS (v3.4), and I am currently styling a map for presentation. I'm trying to match colors within data contained on a layer using "Categorized" styling, so that I can differentiate hierarchy between State/Local/Private/etc roadways, and also do this between discrete layers.

It seems like the way to do this would be to create a "New Palette" of swatches within the "Change Symbol Color" dialogue. Normally, I would expect this would allow me to save a dozen color swatches I like, and then load this palette when styling another item, either within the same layer, or another item on a different layer - but that does not seem to be the way it works. Instead, I find the palette which I've saved, but it is empty with no contents (???). Is this a bug or an environmental variable thing? Do I need to export/save the palette outside of QGIS and load it for each different layer? This seems like a total P.I.A. Anyone else experience this or have a workaraound solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I was just looking in the wrong place - there is in fact a way to setup project-level color palettes in QGIS, but it is in a different spot. If you go to Project -> Properties -> Default Styles this will let you setup symbology defaults for different types of geometry and color-ramps and color palettes too! Once you do this and save it, your new custom palette will automatically show up in your symbol color-pickers!

There is also a whole lot more that can be accomplished with Python (not there yet): [Using Python to generate color palettes](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/user/13/tag/2.6/)

And some ready-made palettes available for download here: [GPL Files for QGIS](http://www.davidrevoy.com/article27/palettes-for-gimp-mypaint-or-krita)

Screen-cap of Default-Styles dialogue (From QGIS 2.6 documentation):
[image: Color Palette Documentation]

Comment: I installed all those lovely pre-made color palettes a while ago, and couldn't remember where I found them. Glad you found them and shared the link.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly where you're seeing a "change symbol color" dialog, but here are a few different ways to save colors and use them again later.

You can add pre-defined colors to the project from the Project menu > Properties > Default Styles.

[image]

You can apply project styles to features from the select color interface > color swatches tab > choose "project colors" from the dropdown menu.

[image]
Notice that in the same interface, you also have the option to choose from *recent* colors. So you can actually skip the step of saving colors in the project menu, and just use recent colors.

For quick access to the options described above, right-clicking on the color in the layer-styling tab opens this menu:

[image]

Notice that you have access to recent colors, standard color palettes, and project colors.

---

The QGIS-3 series has an enormous number of different ways to customize the symbology of your layers. See the [The Style Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#id9) section of the QGIS User Manual.